# Sony Playstation 3 PS3 Won't see Media Server

Tags: macos, tv, xbox360, ps3, dlna

I'm kind of lost, not really sure what to do so if anyone can input me on this I'd highly appreciate it. (I'm getting to the point where I'm about to do something stupid).

I recently purchased a new TV, not that it would make any difference but the model is: KDL-55HX800. That TV supports natively DLNA, so I thought I'd take advantage of that.

prior to using that TV, I was using my old TV w/ XBOX360 hooked up through Apple Airport Express where over WiFi I'd get a signal form my Apple Airport Extreme and over ethernet it'd go to my XBOX360, on my desktop I use [Yazsoft Playback](http://alexus.org/software/yazsoft-playback) software that was working without any problems at all.

so here is what I change, since TV has a way to connect ethernet cable I did that and I moved in my PS3 to same room, so to connect all that I took non-managed small switch and now networking wise everything works, I'm able to obtain IP address for TV, XBOX and PS3 and I'm able to ping from my Desktop all of these devices, yet neither of these devices are able to see my Desktop's DLNA server.

I also used my Motorolla Droid X phone, enabled DLNA server there and all devices now are able to see my new DLNA server, so that makes me think that it's all my Desktop's fault, yet over there I turned off LittleSnitch, Native OSX firewall and through netstat I can see that server is started and able to serve content.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure that there are no permissions set on the streaming server? I'm not an OSX guy, but with my PS3 and Windows Media Player, streaming has to be allowed for that device (PS3). So to sum it up, check for read permissions.


-Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped: [.local - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) .